# Using Moustache syntax in CSS in Laravel

Tags: laravel-blade, laravel-7

How to use {{}} syntax in css file. Because I've a css file which refrences some background images.
....css code

```
background-image: url({{asset(assets/images/landing_page/index.png)}};
```

In the console it gives the following error:

```
127.0.0.1:8000/assets/images/landing_page/index.png 404 (Not Found)
```

it is not showing how can i refrence it with or without {{}} this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```css
background-image: url({{url('assets/images/landing_page/index.png')}});
```